# Elementary set theory, Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder usage, check my proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, solution-verification

I have a question, I was asked to show that $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R$ are of equal cardinality using the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem.

I would just like some feedback, if I solved it correctly:

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x$. it is clear to see that $f$ is injective.

Let $g:\mathbb R\to [0,1]$, $g(x)=arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}$. $g$ is also injective.

Conclusion: They are of equal cardinality.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is fine and indeed is clearly injective. The other functions you want though is a function $g:\mathbb R \to [0,1]$. You can use the $\arctan $ function but not quite in the way you did. You can easily fix this by making sure the functions you will use will be injective, have domain $\mathbb R$, and have codomain $[0,1]$.

Also, when you conclude the two sets have the same cardinality, you might want to clearly indicate that you are invoking the CSB theorem.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: not quite fixed since now your function $g$ does not land in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: got it. $$g(x) = \frac{arctan(x)+\frac{\pi}{2}}{\pi}$$